# Package tsx library into executable

Tags: node.js, typescript, packaging, esbuild, node-tsx

I want to package the typescript-runner [tsx](https://github.com/privatenumber/tsx) into an executable so that it is not dependent on nodejs or npm to be ran. How is this possible? I wanted to use vercel/pkg but it seems to have problems with the esm syntax.

Comment: Since vercel/pkg is deprecated and it redirects to https://nodejs.org/api/single-executable-applications.html, this could be worth looking into. "Deno" does also work on "Single Binary" targets and you will not need tsx.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [nexe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nexe)

```
nexe server.js -r "public/**/*.html"
```

For more CLI options see: `nexe --help`

> ### Motivation and Features
>
> - Self contained applications
> - Ability to run multiple applications with different node.js runtimes.
> - Distribute binaries without needing node / npm.
> - Idempotent builds
> - Start and deploy faster.
> - Lockdown specific application versions, and easily rollback.
> - Flexible build pipeline
> - Cross platform builds

Or if you are familiar with docker, you could create a container of your tsx-runner project along with other containers, you could manage the multi container system with `docker-compose`